# How can I make a bubble chart wait for selecting some values and then display the bubbles

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, bubble-chart

I have a database relating to `flights`, and this a sample of it :

**What I have ?**

This jsfiddle describes what I have now https://jsfiddle.net/salaheddinehajjara/jusjkm8j/48/

```
var dataSet = [{
    "Mkt_Al1" : "4U", // the airline 
    "City_Orig" : "Casablanca",
    "City_Dest" : "Barcelona",
    "Freq" : 2,
    "Op_Days" : "[ \"2\", \"3\" ]" // Operating days : Tuesday and Wednesday
},
{
    "Mkt_Al1" : "3O",
    "City_Orig" : "Stockholm",
    "City_Dest" : "Madrid",
    "Freq" : 3,
    "Op_Days" : "[ \"1\", \"3\", \"5\" ]" //Operating days : Monday, Wednesday and Friday
},
{
    "Mkt_Al1" : "AF",
    "City_Orig" : "Paris",
    "City_Dest" : "Casablanca",
    "Freq" : 3,
    "Op_Days" : "[ \"5\", \"6\", \"7\" ]" //Operating days : Friday, Saturday and Sunday
}]
```

**What I Want ?**

I want to make a `bubble chart` using [dc.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js) and [crossfilter.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js).

Just like the [Nasdaq example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)

**In the x-axis** : I want to have the days of the week, from Monday to

sunday which refers to the `operating days` of the `flight`.

**In the y-axis** : I want to have the `number of flights`.

**Bubbles** : Will contain the `Airlines`.

And I don't how to how to really proceed, because, I want to display this bubbles **after** choosing the `origin` and the `destination` and I don't know to do that because I have in my dahsboard two menu-selectors for the origin and the destination which work fine.

Second thing I don't know how to group my flights by these operating days, because I have tried to create a dimension like this :

```
var days = [['1',"Monday"],['2',"Tuesday"],['3',"Wednesday"],['4',"Thursday"],['5',"Friday"],['6',"Saturday"],['7',"Sunday"]];
var ndx = crossfilter(dataSet);

var Opdays = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  for (var i=3; i<d.Op_Days.length; i+=5) {
    for ( var j=0; j<7; j++) {
          if ( d.Op_Days[i] == days[j][0] )
        return days[j][1]; }}});
```

**The problem ?**

The problem with this code, it returns **just** the **first** operating day and I don't know how to fix that.

Please how can I achieve the above ?

Comment: Who can help please ?

Comment: Can you put together a working example on JSFiddle or a similar site? Here's one you can start with that already contains pretty up to date versions of Crossfilter and dc.js: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/jusjkm8j/

Comment: @EthanJewett Hiii, here it is a sample https://jsfiddle.net/salaheddinehajjara/jusjkm8j/45/ , now I want to add a bubble chart like described above and thank you so much

Comment: Hii again mr @EthanJewett, I don't know if you you could follow me through the jsfiddle or not and thank you ... ;)

Comment: I will look at it when I am able to and let you know.

Comment: I have dealt with the first problem in some apps by having the drop-downs default to some invalid value so that nothing will pass the filter until they are both set.

Comment: As far as the operating days, have you considered moving to the Crossfilter 1.4 alphas? That would allow you to use the new array dimension feature, which seems to be exactly what you want: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays You would need to convert your `Op_Days` data to an array rather than a string.

Comment: I just update it, is that now I could have on my x-axis the days of the week by keeping the frequencies, that is to say, a flight operated on Tuesdays and Saturdays I'll find out these two days?

Comment: @EthanJewett Yes I tried the isarray and it worked, thank you much much

Comment: Please I want to use the crossfilter 1.4 alpha in jsfiddle but I didn't found it in cdn ??

Comment: Hope that some one could help me ...

Comment: @Gordon Hii chief, can I have the first part of the solution please ?